# Extremely Slow Building Bidirection TF Lstm Cell

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am building a bidirectional lstm layer by Tensorflow, but the building process is very slow, it takes likes hours to finish building for a fairly small network. 
my test hidden layer size is 16; input embedding vector size is 32; input sequence length is 20, vocabulary size is 20000

is the performance of tf as expected?

attached the part of I used to build the network for more information:

```
cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hidden_layer_size)
cell_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hidden_layer_size)
(emb_encoder_inputs, fw_state, _) = tf.contrib.rnn.static_bidirectional_rnn(
          cell_fw, cell_bw, emb_encoder_inputs, dtype=tf.float32,
          sequence_length=article_lens)
```

Comment: No, it should be fast, the must time-consuming process is loading the data, esp. if you didn't encode the training data in advance and just do it from scratch in the training process. it would require many hours and lots of memory.

Comment: Hi HaoChien, thanks for your response. I believe I don't involve any data when constructing the network. what I did before this steps are just set up placeholder with size of batch_size *  time_steps for both encoder and decoder.   the most time consuming part is static_bidirectional_rnn, it took much longer time than building forward and backward layer.

Comment: Well, could you show the other part of your code?  since the code you post don't seem to have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

bidirectional_dynamic_rnn is faster than static_bidirectional_rnn.

Comment: Can you include some comments more specific to op case?